# sql error when trying to check if an id exists in three different places in sql database

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, join, select

I am using joins below to check if a specific id exists in three different places in my sql database.

Here is the sql code:

```
SELECT ivrs.greeting 
FROM ivrs 
WHERE ivrs.customer = 1 AND ivrs.greeting = 217 
INNER JOIN ivrs ON ivrs.customer = 1 AND ivrs.menu = 217 
INNER JOIN ivr_dests ON ivr_dests.customer = 1 AND ivr_dests.sound = 217;
```

Here is the node.js code:

```
function deleteFile({ data }) {
  const customer_id = data['customer-id'];
  const sound_id = data['sound_id'];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var pre_sql = `SELECT ivrs.greeting FROM ivrs WHERE ivrs.customer = ${customer_id} AND ivrs.greeting = ${sound_id} INNER JOIN ivrs ON ivrs.customer = ${customer_id} AND ivrs.menu = ${sound_id} INNER JOIN ivr_dests ON ivr_dests.customer = ${customer_id} AND ivr_dests.sound = ${sound_id};`;
    console.log(pre_sql)
    con.query(pre_sql, function (err, pre_result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      resolve(pre_result);
    });

  });
```

As you can see, I am looking to see if sound_id exists within two tables (ivrs (menu and greeting column) and ivr_dests (sound column)). However, currently sql throws an error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN ivrs ON ivrs.customer = 1 AND ivrs.menu = 217 INNER JOIN ivr_dests ON' at line 1
```

I'm pretty sure my syntax is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Let me know! Any help would be much appreciated.

Sample Data:

ivrs:

[image: ivrs]

ivr_dests:

[image: ivr_dests]

Sample outcome:

For example, if customer_id = 1 and sound_id is 217. I should only get
greeting: 217
Same logic is applicable for ivrs.menu and and ivr_dests.sound.

**UPDATE**

With this sql statement,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ivrs.* FROM ivrs INNER JOIN ivr_dests ON ivr_dests.customer = ivrs.customer WHERE ivrs.customer = 1 AND 158 in (ivrs.greeting, ivrs.menu, ivr_dests.sound)
```

I should be returning no value (an empty array). However, it presently returns this:

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, customer: 1, greeting: null, menu: 217 } ]
```

Here is the data for customer 1 presently:

ivrs:

[image: ivrs]

ivr_dests:

[image: ivr_dests]

Comment: `WHERE` has to be after all the `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: So just move the `WHERE` clause to the end.

Comment: The `ON` clauses should contain the relationships between the tables.

Comment: Are you sure you want to join `ivrs` with itself?

Comment: Sample data and desire results would really help.

Comment: @Barmar in my use case i need the sole value of ivrs.greeting or ivrs.menu if and only the id criteria is met for the respective row

Comment: @Barmar sample data and results attached.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sample data and results attached.

Comment: I don't see `menu = 217` in the sample data. Which row should be returned?

Comment: There's no `sound = 217` either

Comment: @Barmar since i am specifying 217 as sound_id, ivrs.greeting value of 217 would be returned. if i was specifying 167, ivrs.menu value of 167 would be returned. if i was specifying 228, the ivr_dests value.sound of 228 would be returned. if there was any overlap both/all three values would be returned

Comment: You need different queries depending on which inputs are known and which you want to get. SQL isn't like a spreadsheet, where you can fill in knowns and it automatically returns the unknowns.

Comment: I still don't understand the logic. You wrote **if customer_id = 1 and sound_id is 217. I should only get greeting: 217** Where is `sound_id = 217` in the sample data?

Comment: @Barmar sound_id is the passed in value from the nodejs script that is used to find if any values match it. checkout the node code for that

Comment: But what is it supposed to match in the sample table?

Comment: @Barmar ivrs.greeting OR ivrs.menu OR ivr_dests.sound

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235719/discussion-between-juliette-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause has to go at the end.

You don't need `ivrs` in both `FROM` and `JOIN`.

The `ON` clause should contain the relationship between the tables. You only want the `ivr_dests` rows with the same customer ID.

You can use `IN` in the `WHERE` clause to test multiple columns for the search value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ivrs.* 
FROM ivrs 
INNER JOIN ivr_dests ON ivr_dests.customer = ivrs.customer
WHERE ivrs.customer = 1 AND 217 in (ivrs.greeting, ivrs.menu, ivrs_dests.sound)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but what about ivrs.menu. If ivrs.menu is equivalent to the id, it should be chosen too/solely chosen.

Comment: I added that to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thank you for your continued support! I tried out your code with the above data sample in the pictures and it returned a blank array. here was the sql statement:

Comment: SELECT ivrs.greeting FROM ivrs INNER JOIN ivr_dests ON ivr_dests.customer = ivrs.customer AND ivr_dests.sound = ivrs.greeting WHERE ivrs.customer = 1 AND ivrs.greeting = 217  AND ivrs.menu = 217

Comment: btw was the semicolon after the ivrs.greeting in the third line a typo?

Comment: It was a copy-paste error, since I just copied your query and moved the WHERE down.

Comment: any reason why it would return an empty array though?

Comment: i can just split it up into multiple queries. might be easier...

Comment: Because nothing matches all the conditions. As I mentioned above, there's no row with both `greeting = 217 AND menu = 217`

Comment: Or create the query dynamically based on the known vs unknown columns.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: think I found a bug in the sql script. refer to update in original post above please.